# CSS: Play animation when div's css attribute changes

Tags: html, css, animation

I would like to create an animation starting when my div's attribute changed using pure CSS.

The div's initial state is:
`display: none;`

Changing `display` attribute to a value unequal `none`, 
a animation should be played (inner glow effect using an inset box shadow).
The change of the attribute can occour multiple times. After every change the animation
should be played.

Is this possible using pure css? Or do I need to use javascript additionally?

```
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.0);  
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-name: card-appear;
```

```
@keyframes card-appear{
    0% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.0); 
    }
    10% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
    }
    20% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
    }
    30% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.6); 
    }
    40% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); 
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1.0); 
    }
    60% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); 
    }
    70% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.6); 
    }
    80% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
    }
    90% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); 
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: share your `html fiddle`

Comment: How does the display property (not attribute) get changed?

Comment: @radulfr There is a superior system which changes the css property using javascript. But this system should not contain custom animations so I would like to implement the animation with pure css.

Comment: Can it be changed so that it changes a class instead of the property itself? I doubt there's a way to detect a property changing in CSS.

Comment: Yes, this solution can work. Adding a class (appear animation) when the superior system changes the div property to 'visible'. The class would run the animation exactly one time. After changing the property to 'not visible' the class is removed.